# Ошибка: Error creating bean with name " ", Invocation of init method failed

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

Ошибка

> WARN 12316 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;
@Autowired
private RoleRepository roleRepository;

@PostConstruct
public void unit() {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername("admin");
    if (user == null) {
        Role role = roleRepository.findByName("admin");
        if (role == null) {
            role.setName("ADMIN"); // Дебагером здесь получаю NullPointerException
            roleRepository.save(role);
        }
        user.setUsername("admin");
        user.setPassword(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode("admin"));
        user.setRoles(new HashSet<>(roleRepository.findAll()));
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

Метод смотрит есть ли пользователь admin и если нет создает его.
Не очень понимаю из за чего ошибка.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Спринг не может инициализировать контекст, т.к. не может создать бин с именем `userServiceImpl`. А создать он не может потому, что в методе объявленном `@PostContructor` возникает исключение.

Ошибка у вас в следующем условии:

```
Role role = roleRepository.findByName("admin");
if (role == null) {
   role.setName("ADMIN"); // Дебагером здесь получаю NullPointerException
   roleRepository.save(role);
}
```

Т.е. происходит проверка `role` на `null` и затем, происходит изменение имени на нулевой ссылке. Это естественно приводит к `NullPointerException`